# concatenating the contents of two pandas columns python unboundlocalerror in ops.py

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe - anydataframe eg.

```
d = ({
    'A' : ['Foo','Bar','Foo','zee'],           
    'B' : ['X','Bar','X','Bar'],
    'C' : ['foo','bar','Nacho','Y'],
    })
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

i want to join two columns in a new column

```
df['UID']=df['A']+df['B']
```

but im getting the unboundlocalerror

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-d763f11a6023>", line 1, in <module>
    df['UID']=df['A']+df['B']

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 723, in wrapper
    result,

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

is my installation corrupt? i can get it to work on my laptop

Comment: can you give clear expected output of df['UID']

Comment: Works on my machine too, no errors.  Looks like a Pandas installation issue.

Comment: Lakshmi it should give a new column called UID that combines columns A & B.     A    B      C     UID
0  Foo    X    foo    FooX
1  Bar  Bar    bar  BarBar
2  Foo    X  Nacho    FooX
3  zee  Bar      Y  zeeBar

Comment: ok uninstall and reinstall fixed this